# Change which URL the cypress test visits at run time

Tags: cypress

While im developping my website the URL changes quite a lot, if I need to restart or something. So at one time it might be 0.0.0.0:5500 and the next time it could 0.0.0.0:34935.

So if I set the: `cy.visit('url)` to be a constant URL then I would constantly have to change it to work.

So I am wondering if there is a way to input the URL at runtime and use that.

Comment: Other than maybe changing it some where in the source code, you could extract it somehow and then pass it along as cli argument to cypress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass in the `baseUrl` as a command line option.

```sh
cypress run --config baseUrl=0.0.0.0:33935
cypress run --config baseUrl=0.0.0.0:5500
```

If you didn't want to use a command line variable, but wanted to execute strictly off of if you can reach an endpoint, you could overwrite the `cy.visit()` command to ping one of the endpoints before navigating to it.

```js
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('visit', (originalFn, url, options) => {
  cy.request({ url: 'http://0.0.0.0:5500', failOnStatusCode: false}).then((res) => {
    if (res.status === 200) {
      return '0.0.0.0:5500'
    }
    return '0.0.0.0:33935'
  }).then((baseUrl) => {
    return originalFn(`${baseUrl}${url}`, options);
  });
})
```

Note that this solution will ping your endpoints before every `cy.visit()`. There's probably a more elegant way to do this, involving having a dummy url for your `baseUrl` in cypress.json, and only do this request if `Cypress.env('baseUrl')` is still that dummy url.

Comment: so when you visit a website would you do cy.visit(baseUrl)?

Comment: You would call `cy.visit()` as you normally would, with the relative link. `cy.visit()` will normally supply the baseUrl from `cypress.json` (or wherever that config variable has been set) and append the url to that baseUrl. But, if Cypress is provided an absolute link, it will just visit it. And in our case, that's what we're doing.

Comment: So the way that I run cypress is through ```npm run cypress:open``` 
Is there a way to add the url into there and then pass it through to the cypress run command?

Comment: You can override a value set in the your `cypress.json` when executing the npm script by adding a `CYPRESS_*` variable before the command. Something like `CYPRESS_BASE_URL=http://0.0.0.0:5500 npm run cypress:open`

Comment: Or, you could make two custom scripts that pass in different baseUrl values, like `"cypress:open:5500": "npx cypress run --config baseUrl=0.0.0.0:5500"`. You can replace `cypress run` with `cypress open` if that's your existing command for the script.

Answer (score -1):

You are doing it wrong. Why your port for the application changes all the time. Rather than asking your developer to make your application accessible on port 8080 or some fixed port, you are exploring other options which is not required at all.